# How can I know the AR.Drone's height in order to control it?

Tags: ros, ardrone2.0, rostopic, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried for getting the value of **"altd"** in /ardrone/navdata and what ever the position of the drone and even the state of drone like flying, landing, landed.. etc the **"altd"** value is always zero. I want to use this value for many things so please someone help me in getting the height of the drone.

Below is the screenshot of navdata of my drone when subscribed to /ardrone/navdata topic:

http://i58.tinypic.com/29wr2au.png

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206849/how-can-i-know-the-ar.drone%27s-height-in-order-to-control-it?/) by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 228 on 2015-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2015-05-15**:
What is the firmware version of the AR-Drone? Is it AR-Drone 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that you can get altitude data even if it is not in flight by subscribing to the `/ardrone/navdata_altitude` topic. You will have to modify the `ardrone.launch` file so that the `enable_navdata_pressure_raw` parameter is set to true. Just copy and paste this:

```
<param name="enable_navdata_pressure_raw" value="true" />
```

and add it between the `<node>` and `</node>` tags of the launch file. In order to use this data you will have to include the `navdata_altitude` message/datatype and access it in your callback function using `data.altitude_raw`.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saikishor](https://answers.ros.org/users/21247/saikishor/) on 2017-02-19**:
Wow, that sounds cool and I think it will work.
Thank you. It is helpful.